# What is the cost of enabling memory profiling?

Tags: r, build, compilation, default

`R`'s default [configuration options](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Configuration-options) disable memory profiling, shared-library `libR`, static-library `libR.a`, `GNU` `gettext`, `valgrind` headers, and link-time optimisation.

Some of these (like `valgrind`) must just be because not everyone will use it. Others might be answered elsewhere on SO (like [Is there any reason why not to use link time optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736507/is-there-any-reason-why-not-to-use-link-time-optimization) might answer `--enable-lto[=no]`).

But what is the possible disadvantage or cost of enabling memory profiling in `R`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, apparently the answer can be found from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprofmem.html:

> The memory profiler slows down `R` even when not in use, and so is a compile-time option.