# negative number is printing

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and trying to understand data types.

I specified following variables:

```
  int nsamples = 10000000;
  int n = 32;
  int m = 64;


  int nrpoinnts = n*m*nsamples+99;
  printf("Nr points %d\n",nrpoinnts);
```

For some reason the printed number is negative. Why is that happening? I tough the value range of nrpoinnts was exceeded, so I checked double. The final result was that I was getting negative value either.

Comment: Because it overflows the max positive 32 bit integer. Try using long long integer and %lld.

Comment: check [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052088/why-int-i-400400-400-gives-result-72-is-datatype-circular) for a proper explanation.

Comment: If you want to check the value using `double`, you need to force at least one of `n`, `m` or `nsamples` to a floating point value in the calculation as otherwise the calculation is done using integer arithmetic and the result converted to `double`.  Hence: `double num_points = (double)n * m * nsamples + 99;` would yield a positive floating point value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit/range of signed `int` or just `int` you are using, even on a **64** bit machine with a **4** byte integer is **2,147,483,647** (as its maximum value) and **−2,147,483,648** (as its minimum value) - the value you are trying to generate/print is **20480000000** which is greater than the limit/range - hence it is wrapping and producing -ve results.

Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",2147483647+1);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `−2147483648`

Use **long unsigned** instead of `int` to contain the result.

Answer (score 3):

The value of your multiplication is `20,480,000,000`.
If `int` is 4 bytes long on your system, then the maximum value it can have is `2,147,483,647`.
You can check the value of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` macros defined in `limits.h`
The values of both these macros are compiler dependent because `sizeof(int)` is implementation defined in both C & C++.

When this `INT_MAX` value is exceeded, it prints a negative value in this particular instance. But note that *signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour* as per the standard.

So, you can use `unsigned long long` instead of `int` to store the value of your arithmetic operation.

Comment: _"then the maximum value it can have is 4,294,967,295"_: not quite, remember that `int` is signed.

Comment: Updated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 int nrpoinnts
```

to

```
 unsigned long int nrpoinnts
```