# printf("%d\n", 4294967296); makes some strange errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

(4294967296=2^32)

I want to print `4294967296` using printf("%u, %d") and want to see what will happen but i get some strange result.

The code is as following:

```
printf("%d\n", 4294967296);

printf("d = %u = %d = 0x%x  \n", 4294967296, 4294967296, 4294967296);//this is strange

printf("d = %u = %d = 0x%x  \n", 4294967295 + 1, 4294967295 + 1, 4294967295 + 1);
```

and my result is

```
0

d = 0 = 1 = 0x0

d = 0 = 0 = 0x0
```

[the picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPKEA.png)

you can see the binary expression of 4294967296 is 0x0 in the second line, but when i print 4294967296 use "%d", it will show 1, which i am confused with. I expect the output of 1 to be 0.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", 4294967296);` invokes *undefined behavior* [C11-Standard 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9).

Comment: The %d and %u formatting arguments expect a 32-bit argument to be passed to printf().  But the code actually passes 64-bit arguments, 0x0000000100000000 in hex.  So the %d makes it read the lower 32-bits of that value, which is 0.  The next %u makes it read the upper 32-bits of that value, which is 1.  Little-endian machine btw.  Doesn't happen in the second statement since 4294967295 + 1 produces a 32-bit value.  If your compiler doesn't warn about this then be sure to either update it or crank up the warning level.

Comment: @HansPassant "4294967295 + 1 produces a 32-bit value" --> depends on C89 vs C99.  With modern C, 4294967295 is also a `long long` and `4294967295 + 1` is a 64-bit value.

Answer (score 5):

If supported then the value `4294967296` is a `long long`, because it doesn't fit in an `unsigned int`.

The format `"%d"` is for `int` (a *signed* `int`).

Mismatching value type and format specifier leads to *undefined behavior*.

The value `4294967295` *does* fit in an `unsigned int` but then you add `1` making it overflow.

The range of a 32-bit unsigned integer is `0` to `2³²-1` (inclusive).

Comment: "The value 4294967295 does fit in an unsigned int" is true, yet `4294967295` is still a `long long` _decimal constant_ since C99.  "add 1 making it overflow" --> No. that sum is `long long` 4294967296. Your answer makes sense for C89 where `4294967295` is an `unsigned long` (and adding 1 is well defined).

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned integer never overflow:

> (C99, 6.2.5p9) "A computation involving unsigned operands can never
>   overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
>   unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater
>   than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."

But in C, integer overflows are undefined behavior:

> (C99, 6.5.5p5) "If an exceptional condition occurs during the
>   evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type), the behavior is undefined."
>
> (C99, 3.4.3p3) "EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the
>   behavior on integer overflow."

I'm quoting these from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052088/why-int-i-400400-400-gives-result-72-is-datatype-circular) to a question that I asked previously.

Comment: There is no signed integer overflow here.

Answer (score 1):

> printf(“%d\n”, 4294967296); makes some strange errors

Yes it does - a most interesting question.

---

This comes down to what is the *type* of 4294967295 and 4294967296?

Is the type determined by fitting in:
    `int, long, unsigned long` (C89)
    `int, long, long long` (C99)
    `int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long` (Perhaps VS2017)

Note: `4294967295 + 1` is not signed integer overflow in any case.

---

This is one of the places where C89, C99 (or later) differ and where VS2017 does its own thing.

---

**With compliant C89**, (32-bit world)  4294967295 is a `unsigned long` *decimal constant* and adding 1 is `unsigned long` 0.  (C89 6.1.3.2)

As `...` arguments, an `int 0` and `unsigned 0` both work for `"%u"` and `"%d"` and the value of 0 is in range for both.  Yet this is an `unsigned long 0` and so technical undefined behavior (UB).  On 32-bit systems, this UB is often benign and results in the same as printing a `unsigned 0`.

4294967296 is simply an out of range constant.

---

**With C99** (or later - certainly not OP's case), 4294967295 is a `long long` *decimal constant*<sup>1</sup> and adding 1 is simply `long long` 4294967296.  4294967296 is another `long long` *decimal constant*

Passing a `long long` to match a `"%d"` or `"%u"` is *undefined behavior*. The same output of "0, 1, 0" in **both** cases would be an "expected" UB.

---

Yet OP is using **VS2017** and 4294967295 is a `unsigned long` *decimal constant* (per C89 rules) and [int, long int, or unsigned long int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/integer-types?view=vs-2019) and adding 1 is `unsigned long` 0. Printing that with `%u,%d` is technically UB, but with 32-bit `unsigned` having the same characteristic as 32-bit `unsigned long` the 0,0,0 output is reasonable.

4294967296 is apparently some 64-bit type (such as `long long`)<sup>2</sup>  and per C99 rules is UB.  Output of 0, 1, 0 is reasonable, yet not resilient.

OP's result may differ depending on [/Za, /Ze (Disable Language Extensions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2019).

---

<sup>1</sup> or a 64-bit `long`.

<sup>2</sup> I was unable to find a definitive on-line VS2017 ref for the type of a **C** decimal constant, (not C++) for values more than  4294967295.